# Discounted Cash Flows in Excel

Tags: equities, valuation, dcf

I'm taking an online class on stock valuation. In my class, the instructor calculated stock intrinsic value using XNPV function in Excel. While I understand this part, I don't know why it gives a different result from myself manually discounting each cash flow and summing up everything.

All XNPV calculation is done by the instructor, and he got 599,588. I got 599,996 if I do everything manually.

I think this may be a math problem. Can someone enlighten me?

The Excel file is [here.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ilx1HhXsWUyx1aAiAu0mHl9vlN4EnkFv)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: This (small) difference is likely due to different Day Count conventions (as often happens in i.r. calculations). Excel uses exact day counts (for example there are 275 days between 20180331 and 20181231) and assumes 365 days per year. This means that the first period is 0.753424658 years long. Your calculation on the other hand assumed 0.75 years (i.e. 9 equal months in a 12 month year). As long as you consistently use 1 method for all your calculations there should not be any problem. It is not useful to argue "which method is right".

Comment: Got it. Thanks!
I'm overly obsessed with a small difference. Not good.

Comment: No, you need to be very careful in this business, you have the right attitude: check everything. ;)  Good luck !

Comment: Hi I found another problem - I used the Yearfrac function in excel to calculate the day count conversion. Setting 3/31/2018 as the start date and 12/31/2018 as the end date, I got exactly 0.75, not 0.7534..... Any idea why?

Comment: OK. The Yearfrac() function has a third argument which specifies what Day Count convention to use. If you leave it out it defaults to 0, which is the US Money Market convention that assumes each month has 30 days and there are 12 months or 360 days in a year (this is what is used for example for US T-bills and bank CDs calculations, and what you used). If you want the Actual/Actual convention you need a third argument equal to 1, and if you want Actual/365 you need a 3 (the difference between these only matters in a leap year). So you can choose how Yearfrac() behaves according to need.

Comment: Great. Thanks again!